# Google App Engine writes painfully slow - how to fix

Tags: google-app-engine, models

I have some pretty simple models that I need to optimize as my writes to app engine using python are painfully slow. Here are my models (example not actual)

```
class Library(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    books = db.ListProperty(db.Key) #usually between 20 - 200 items

class Book(db.Model):
    author = db.ReferenceProperty(Author)

class Author(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

def add_library(books):
    library = Library(name="bob's")

    for book in books:
        lbook = Book() 
        author = Author(name="tom")
        author.put()
        lbook.author = author
        lbook.put()
        library.books.append(lbook)
    library.put()
```

This usually takes between 8 to 20 seconds to insert 1 Library, is this normal? How can I optimize this to be more efficient

Comment: Do your puts in a batch?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the data model you proposed here.  You cannot have a large number of list of keys on one side of relationship, as described in this article - http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html

Also, the for-loop in your code segment for inserting a library record also inserts all the authors and books sequentially.  Assuming about 40ms for each datastore put(), and assuming you have 50 books and 50 authors, it will take 4 seconds, a long time!  And finally your library record gets created.

Instead of having a list of books on the Library side, you can define your models as follows:

```
class Library(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Book(db.Model):
    author = db.ReferenceProperty(Author)
    library = db.ReferenceProperty(Library, collection_name = 'books')
```

In this case, your books define which library it belongs to.  You can just create the library once, and reference all the books to it.  When you want to fetch books, you can do

```
for book in my_library.books:
    // Do something with books
```

It will still take 40ms for entering each book, but atleast you can enter books independently and reference to the library, which has already been created.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Mani's answer, your code currently creates an author for each book. In datastore, it's usually better to create one large entity instead of many small, so you could try to inline the authors into the book entities (e.g. by directly storing an author_name in book) and save storing two independent entities.